# switch statement does not respond to condition

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to get my background color to change depending on the type of severity a user reports. I've got it hardcoded now just for testing purposes.

The problem is that when I log the severity[randomSeverity] it gives te correct values, but the switch statement does not seem to listen to it?

```
const severity =['Extreme', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'Trivial']
const randomSeverity = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5))

var bgcolor = () => {
    switch(severity[randomSeverity]){
      case 'Extreme':
        bgcolor = 'bg-red-600'
        break
      case 'High':
        bgcolor = 'bg-orange-600'
        break
      case 'Medium':
        bgcolor = 'bg-yellow-600'
        break
      case 'Low':
        bgcolor = 'bg-green-300'
        break
      case 'Trivial':
        bgcolor = 'bg-green-600'
        break
      default:
        bgcolor = 'bg-white'
        console.log('init')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You store a **[function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)** in the variable `bgcolor`:

```
var bgcolor = () => { ... }
```

But then you never **call** that function. And even if you would... it is a strange construct to assign a function that then should override itself with a value.

If you remove the function parts around that body of code, it will work:

```js
const severity = ['Extreme', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'Trivial']
const randomSeverity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)

var bgcolor;

switch (severity[randomSeverity]) {
  case 'Extreme':
    bgcolor = 'bg-red-600'
    break
  case 'High':
    bgcolor = 'bg-orange-600'
    break
  case 'Medium':
    bgcolor = 'bg-yellow-600'
    break
  case 'Low':
    bgcolor = 'bg-green-300'
    break
  case 'Trivial':
    bgcolor = 'bg-green-600'
    break
  default:
    bgcolor = 'bg-white'
    console.log('init')
}

console.log(randomSeverity);
console.log(severity[randomSeverity]);
console.log(bgcolor);
```

Furthermore, I simplified `Math.floor(5)` to just `5`, it makes no sense to try rounding down an integer because it will return the same value anyway.